# How do I send info to this API using cURL and PUT?

Tags: php, json, put

I am working with an API that is documented here: https://cutt.ly/BygHsPV

The documentation is a bit thin, but I am trying to understand it the best I can. There will not be a developer from the creator of the API available before the middle of next week, and I was hoping to get stuff done before that.

Basically what I am trying to do is update the consent of the customer. As far as I can understand from the documentation under API -> Customer I need to send info through PUT to /customers/{customerId}. That object has an array called "communicationChoices".

Going into Objects -> CustomerUpdate I find "communicationChoices" which is specified as "Type: list of CommunicationChoiceRequest". That object looks like this:

```
{
  "choice": true,
  "typeCode": ""
}
```

Doing my best do understand this, I have made this function:

```
function update_customer_consent() {
    global $userPhone, $username, $password;

    // Use phone number to get correct user
    $url = 'https://apiurlredacted.com/api/v1/customers/' . $userPhone .'?customeridtype=MOBILE';

    // Initiate cURL.
    $ch = curl_init( $url );

    // Specify the username and password using the CURLOPT_USERPWD option.
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password );

    // Tell cURL to return the output as a string instead
    // of dumping it to the browser.
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    // Data to send

    $data = [
        "communicationChoices" => [
            "communicationChoiceRequest" => [
                "choice" => true,
                "typeCode" => "SMS"
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $json_payload = json_encode($data);

    print_r($json_payload);

    // Set other options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_payload)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_payload);

    // Execute the cURL request

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Check for errors.
    if( curl_errno( $ch ) ) :
       // If an error occured, throw an Exception.
       throw new Exception( curl_error( $ch ) );
    endif;

    if (!$response)
    {
        return false;
    } else {
        // Decode JSON
        $obj = json_decode( $response );
    }

    print_r($response);

}
```

I understand that this is very hard to debug without knowing what is going on within the API and with limited documentation, but I figured asking here was worth a shot anyway.

Basically, $json_payload seems to be a perfectly fine JSON object. The response from the API however, is an error code that means unknown error. So I must be doing something wrong. Maybe someone has more experience with APIs and such documentation and can see what I should really be sending and how.

Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated!

Comment: They say somthing in the API documentation  about: Add annotation ApiResponseObject to document the returned object. Maybe you can do that, not sure how

Answer (score 0):

before you test your code, you can use the form provided on the API Documentation.

when you navigate to `API > Customers > /customers/{customerId}` (GET), you will see a form on the right side of the page (scroll up). you need to provide the required values on the form then hit Submit button. you will surely get a valid data for `communicationChoices` based on the result from the Response Text section below the Submit button.

now, follow the data structure of `communicationChoices` object that you get from the result and try the same on `API > Customers > /customers/{customerId}` (PUT) form.

using the API forms, you may be able to instantly see a success or error from your input (data structure), then translate it to your code.